# Running Cucumber Scenarios in parallel using cucumber-groovy

Tags: java, groovy, automated-tests, cucumber

I am trying to update a project that uses Groovy's Cucumber implementation.  I am getting the following error when trying to run:

`./gradlew cucumber -Denv=test -Ptags=@myTest --continue --no-daemon`

```
Error: Could not find or load main class io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
```

I see the relevant dependency locally

[image]

and from my IntelliJ Run Configuration, I am able to set the `Main class:io.cucumber.core.cli.Main` with no errors. Yet when I run from this context, it gives me undefined step definition errors, despite being able to click through to the Step Defs from the feature files.

I am using Gradle (from wrapper context) 5.0

The section that declares the jar in the `cucumber` task in the `build.gradle` is:

```
    doLast {
    javaexec {
        main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
        classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
        systemProperty "parallel", System.properties.getProperty("parallel", setParallel)
        if (setParallel == "true") cucumberArgs.addAll(cucumberThreadsOption)
        args = cucumberArgs
        jvmArgs = [
                "-Denv=$env",
        ]
    }
}
```

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-core:5.1.3"
    implementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-groovy:5.1.3"
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.6"
}
```

Wonder if there is anything obvious?